# how to properly handle binder entities?

Tags: rest, solid

I have categories and products, now I want to make endpoints according to the REST API, I have to do this: `/categories/123/products`. But then I have to return products from CategoryService? Isn't that a solid violation?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question with source code examples? Which SOLID principle is violated there?